# Dockable windows are not reinstated correctly

Tags: mfc, dockable-windows

This is my first question in this community. I always search a lot when having problems and I always find an answer. But not in this one. Maybe I am not asking Google correctly.
Anyways this looks like a bug to me but I might get it wrong.
Using VS2012 (or 2013) I create the default Multiple documents MFC application. I do not write a single line of code. I compile and run. Then as a user I dock the properties window which by default is at the right to the output window as shown below .
[image: Picture1]

Then I close the application and restart. The window is where it should be but with different width as shown below

[image: Picture2]

If you dock the window to the right (in the view and not in another window) then there is no problem. The position and width are restored just fine. Also this only happens if the main window is maximized. The behaviour, if the main window is not, is as expected.
Do you think it is actually how Microsoft wanted to make this work or they missed that? Is there a workaround for this?
Again forgive me if this question has been asked before but really...
I couldn't find anything.
Appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: This can be very annoying indeed! Not sure if there is a fix, but would love to hear about it then. This is one of the reasons we're paying for another library to use on top of MFC, _replacing_ the built-in tools (which came from BCG, and already had the same problem then - seems it's never been fixed). It gets even worse if you resize the main window to it's minimum size and then back again (drag bottom right corner) - you'll have to go search for the panes.. Same problem when double clicking on the pane headers to undock/dock them. Only if you're lucky they stay somewhat on the same place.

Comment: @Danny_ds which is that library you are paying for ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz - Not sure if this is allowed here, but since this problem is so annoying, here we go: I use [Codejock](http://www.codejock.com/products/toolkitpro/) instead. The panes stay pixel perfect no matter what you do. But it's a bit of a shame actually that we have to use another library on top of MFC just to fix the basics. In general, CodeJock seems to be more stable too, less flickering, takes less resources when using a lot of tabs for example, etc.. To be complete: I used to use [BCG](http://www.bcgsoft.com/bcgsuite.htm), which is now partly integrated in MFC.

Comment: @Danny_ds, thanks for the in formation. I've heard about Codejock already.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!